# VBA Type Mismatch when defining workbook name

Tags: excel, vba, syntax-error

I have the following code that first defines a filepath and then will eventually open a workbook and print a specific sheet to pdf.

However, I get a type mismatch error when trying to set the workbook variable "wb". It highlights the **&** and wont run.

Am I setting the variable wrong?

```
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim FILE_PATH As String
Dim FILE_NAME As String
Dim loc As Worksheet


FILE_PATH = "Users\auser\Documents\Test"
FILE_NAME = "Email_Print_Test"
Set wb = "C:\" & FILE_PATH & "\" & FILE_NAME & ".xlsb"
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("New_Sheet")

loc = wb.ws
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign a `String` to a `Workbook` object.

What you need is to use `Workbooks.Open` to open the workbook. This method returns a `Workbook` Object.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim FILE_PATH As String
    Dim FILE_NAME As String
    Dim loc As Worksheet
    
    
    FILE_PATH = "Users\auser\Documents\Test"
    FILE_NAME = "Email_Print_Test"

    ' Use method here
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\" & FILE_PATH & "\" & FILE_NAME & ".xlsb")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("New_Sheet")
    
    loc = wb.ws
End Sub
```